# Getting 'undefined' from asynchronous response despite 'await' and 'then'

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to send a `GET` request, parse its response and return it to another method. Apparently I have problems handling the asynchronous response.

I want to use Node.js' standard modules, so no Axios.

```
// class 1: Calling API, processing and returning the response

export async function getData() {
  let str = '';

  const options = {
    hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    path: '/posts/',
    method: 'GET',
    json: true,
  };

  https
    .get(options, response => {
      response.on('data', chunk => {
        str += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        return parseJson(str);
      });
    })
    .on('error', error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

async function parseJson(str) {
  const json = JSON.parse(str);
  var text;
  try {
    json.forEach(element => {
      text += element.body;
    });
    // console.log(text); // I'm getting the expected output
    return text;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
}


// class 2: Calling the 2 methods above

getData().then(function (value) {
  console.log('DATA: ' + value); // this is called first
});
```

Unfortunately as output I get an `undefined`. Despite using `async` and `then`:

```
DATA: undefined
```

Comment: you don't return anything in `getData` hint: there's no promises in `getData` - so, `await`ing it makes NO sense

Comment: So `return https.get` should solve the problem?

Comment: no, thought it would, but `https.get` does NOT return a Promise ... you'll need to wrap https.get in a Promise (that you return) and resolve/reject as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change getData as follows

```
export function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let str = '';

        const options = {
            hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
            path: '/posts/',
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
        };

        https.get(options, response => {
            response.on('data', chunk => {
                str += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    const result = parseJson(str);
                    resolve(result);
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
            response.on('error', reject);
        })
        .on('error', reject);
    });
}
```

Now it returns a Promise, which resolves to the result of `parseJson(str)` or rejects with the error at `on('error'`

And `parseJson` as follows - doesn't need to be `async` since there's nothing asynchronous about the code inside it

Also, removing the try/catch in `parseJson` and using try/catch in `.on("end"` means that you can reject the promise returned by `getData` if there's an error in the `parseJson` call

```
function parseJson(str) {
    const json = JSON.parse(str);
    let text = '';
    json.forEach(element => {
        text += element.body;
    });
    return text;
}
```

alternatively (IMHO better)

```
function parseJson(str) {
    const data = JSON.parse(str); // call it data, not json
    return data.map(({body}) => body).join('');
}
```

or even

```
const parseJson = (str) => JSON.parse(str).map(({body}) => body).join('');
```

But that's not important :p

Comment: yes, I know @t.niese - I'm lazy with rejection code rewrites :p

Comment: @t.niese - I've implemented your corrections - thanks again - NOW I've actually implemented the `response.on('error', reject)` :p forgot to do that with my previous edit

Comment: `I'm lazy with rejection code rewrites` you shouldn't, that results in really hard-to-debug code in case of errors. In general, you want to have the code within a `new Promise` block as short as possible to be sure you handle each possible error case. Something like that is much more maintainable: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ms3cya8/)

Comment: @t.niese - I didn't mean with MY code, my code is beautiful and could win awards :p, but the main issue with the OP's code was not the rejections :p -also, changing peoples code too much in an answer can lead to confusion

Comment: Well but the one asking the question here has obviously problems with understanding asynchronous code correctly. So it is even more important to provide a good solution. I mean if you ask a question here about a topic you don't fully understand, you likely would hope to get a solution that properly solves the problem ;).

Comment: `changing peoples code too much in an answer can lead to confusion` I agree with that, but you should then at least mention that there are other problems within the code.